# Render view to string in QueueBackgroundWorkItem does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

So I have a method that renders a view and saves it as string:

```
public class HtmlFactory
{
    private DetailsController controller = ViewRenderer.CreateController<DetailsController>();

    public string writeAbout(contextDB db)
    {
        string str = "";
        var model = VMF.GetAboutViewModel(true, db);
        str = RenderPartialViewToString(controller, "~/Areas/ControlCenter/Views/Details/About.cshtml", model);
        return str;
    }

    private string RenderPartialViewToString(Controller controller, string viewName, object model)
    {
        controller.ViewData.Model = model;

        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName, "~/Areas/ControlCenter/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml");

            var viewContext = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, controller.ViewData, controller.TempData, sw);
            try
            {
                viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // errors caught here
                Console.Write(e.StackTrace);
            }

            return sw.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

When I call `HtmlFactory.writeAbout()` from an MVC action everything works fine:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public void writeIt()
    {
        var HF = new HtmlFactory();
        HF.writeAbout(db);
    }
}
```

But when I try calling it as a background task I get an error:

```
    public void writeIt()
    {
        var HF = new HtmlFactory();
        HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(ct => HF.writeAbout(db));
    }
```

I get the error in this line: `viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);`.
The error:

> Value does not fall within the expected range.

and this is the stack trace:

> at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
>
> at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.GetServerVariableInternal(String name)
>
> at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.GetServerVariable(String name)
>
> at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.GetRemoteAddress()
>
> at System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest.IsLocal()
>
> at System.Web.HttpRequestWrapper.get_IsLocal()
>
> at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
>
> at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
>
> at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage()
>
> at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
>
> at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
>
> at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
>
> at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
>
> at mySite.Factories.HtmlFactory.RenderPartialViewToString(Controller controller, String viewName, Object model)

How can I make it work as a background operation?

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem but you're passing in a controller containing a request that is likely already fulfilled before the background worker is done.

Comment: @Shoe I've added the controller initiation to the HtmlFactory class. The error remains.